# Git difftool problem: unable to create temp-file

Tags: git, difftool

I'm using git with Kaleidoscope configured as the difftool.  It's been working fine for months.  It was working a day or two ago as well.  Today, when I tried doing a "git difftool", suddenly, git reports

```
fatal: unable to create temp-file: No such file or directory
```

Searching around on google suggested that this might be a directory permission problem in the local git repo.  But the situation did not improve even after a recursive chown on the git repo.

Git-difftool documentation does not mention *where* it might be trying to create this temp file.  Does anybody have any ideas on how to find this out?

Comment: What is the value of `$TMPDIR` on your Git server?

Comment: Good catch!  $TMPDIR was set to something crazy "/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.W1I4ev/tmp".  After a bit of googling, this is apparently an known issue with an installer of an app (TotalTerminal).  It did a self update today, but I didn't figure it would actually break something.

Comment: excellent. I have posted an answer with those elements, for more visibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I commented, this kind of message depends usually on the value of the environment variable `$TMPDIR`.

In the OP's case:

> `$TMPDIR` was set to something crazy "`/private/tmp/PKInstallSandbox.W1I4ev/tmp`".
>   After a bit of googling, this is apparently an known issue with an installer of an app ([TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/)).
>   It did a self update today, but I didn't figure it would actually break something.

Restoring `$TMPDIR` to a "sane" value (like `/tmp` or other [MacOs-specific localtion](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-userlevel/2008/Sep/msg00003.html)) should fix the issue.

Comment: How do you set $TMPDIR to /tmp?

Comment: @dmackerman depending on your shell, you would write `export TMPDIR=/tmp` in your `.cshrc` for instance, in order for your session to inherit automatically the right value.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to set it to just "/tmp" as it implies it should be shared by all the users. Then you would get permission problems when two users try to read or write to the same file. Also, by default, "/tmp" is owned by root anyway. By default, it seems OS X set some user-specific folder with a random value such as "/var/folders/e4/xytn52r93F56k0b6646m3d480000gn/D/"

Comment: @Laurent I agree, you can set $TMPDIR to any value that works for your account and your OS.